# Выровнять элементы

Tags: html, css

Всё никак не могу выровнять элементы, при одних размерах внутренних элементов кажется, что все отлично, но когда добавляю больше содержимого, то некоторые псевдоэлементы перестают стыковаться и всё рушится. Также это зависит от размеров экрана.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Может у кого-то есть решение получше, чтобы реализовать такую границу "змейкой"?

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden auto;
  background: black;
}

.company-section {
  *,
  *:before,
  *:after {
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
  }
}

.company-items {
  margin: 0 40px;
}

.company-item {
  padding: 115px 150px;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 1px solid #90989e;
}

.company-item::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #90989e;
}

.company-item:nth-child(odd)::before {
  right: 100%;
  /* margin: 0px 0; */
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.company-item:nth-child(even)::before {
  left: 100%;
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

.company-item::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #90989e;
}

.company-item:first-child::after {
  top: -1px;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100vw;
}

.company-item:nth-child(odd):last-child::after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

.company-item:nth-child(even):last-child::after {
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  width: 100vw;
}

.company-item-container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  /* padding: 2rem; */
}

.company-item:nth-child(even) .company-item-container {
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: reverse;
  -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.company-subtitle {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font: normal 400 36px/1em "Sreda";
  color: #fff;
}

.company-icon {
  display: none;
}

.company-text {
  width: 420px;
  font: normal 400 18px/1.5em "Poppins";
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="company-section">
  <div class="company-container">
    <div class="company-content">
      <div class="company-items">
        <div class="company-items-container">
          <div class="company-item">
            <div class="company-item-container">
              <div class="company-subtitle">
                <h3>Digital Marketing</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="company-icon"><img src="img/icons/1-7dm.svg" alt=""></div>
              <div class="company-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Sem vulputate arcu convallis aliquam diam sagittis tortor. Scelerisque nunc augue ornare pretium egestas at ut nec in. </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="company-item">
            <div class="company-item-container">
              <div class="company-subtitle">
                <h3>Digital Marketing</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="company-icon"><img src="img/icons/1-7dm.svg" alt=""></div>
              <div class="company-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Sem vulputate arcu convallis aliquam diam sagittis tortor. Scelerisque nunc augue ornare pretium egestas at ut nec in. </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="company-item">
            <div class="company-item-container">
              <div class="company-subtitle">
                <h3>Digital Marketing</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="company-icon"><img src="img/icons/1-7dm.svg" alt=""></div>
              <div class="company-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Sem vulputate arcu convallis aliquam diam sagittis tortor. Scelerisque nunc augue ornare pretium egestas at ut nec in. </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="company-item">
            <div class="company-item-container">
              <div class="company-subtitle">
                <h3>Digital Marketing</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="company-icon"><img src="img/icons/1-7dm.svg" alt=""></div>
              <div class="company-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Sem vulputate arcu convallis aliquam diam sagittis tortor. Scelerisque nunc augue ornare pretium egestas at ut nec in. </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="company-item">
            <div class="company-item-container">
              <div class="company-subtitle">
                <h3>Dynamic Management</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="company-icon"><img src="img/icons/1-7dm.svg" alt=""></div>
              <div class="company-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Sem vulputate arcu convallis aliquam diam sagittis tortor. Scelerisque nunc augue ornare pretium egestas at ut nec in. </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="company-item">
            <div class="company-item-container">
              <div class="company-subtitle">
                <h3>Development Modeling</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="company-icon"><img src="img/icons/1-7dm.svg" alt=""></div>
              <div class="company-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Sem vulputate arcu convallis aliquam diam sagittis tortor. Scelerisque nunc augue ornare pretium egestas at ut nec in. </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="company-item">
            <div class="company-item-container">
              <div class="company-subtitle">
                <h3>Digital Marketing</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="company-icon"><img src="img/icons/1-7dm.svg" alt=""></div>
              <div class="company-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Sem vulputate arcu convallis aliquam diam sagittis tortor. Scelerisque nunc augue ornare pretium egestas at ut nec in. </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: тот код который вы предоставили работает как надо. В чем проблема то?

Comment: @Maneken на втором скриншоте предоставлена проблема(

Comment: Стандартная проблема округления суб-пикселей, когда физические пиксели монитора и логические пиксели браузера не совпадают по размеру. Подобной версткой вы эту проблему никак не решите, все равно найдуться девайсы, где такая змейка сломается на уровне суб-пикселей. Вот как вы можете решить эту проблему: между вашими контейнерами есть горизонталная линия. Вот эту линию сверстайте отдельным ЦЕЛЬНЫМ блоком с углами слева и справа загнутыми вверх и вниз. А у самих контейнеров справа и слева - только вертикальные линии без углов. То есть углы с вертикальных линий перенесите на горизонтальную.